# Convert String to Integer using FasterXML Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I'm consuming two JSONs.

The first one has the ID as a String.

```
"details": {
    "id": "316.0"
}
```

The other one has the ID as Integer.

```
"details": {
    "detailId": 316
}
```

Both JSONs are being mapped with FasterXML to two different classes. I want both ids to be Integer. For now they are String.

How can I force ForceXML to convert "316.0" to Integer so I can compare both attributes easily?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Jackson actually handles coercion, so that if property has type `int` or `java.lang.Integer`, it will parse JSON Strings, not just use JSON Numbers.
Reverse is possible as well, using `@JsonFormat(shape=Shape.STRING)` for numeric fields.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't always have the same format, the best way to do it is to retrieve it as a string and parse it :

```
int detailId = (int) Float.parseFloat(node.path("details").asText());
```

Comment: Do you need to use asText(), perhaps there is a method which returns a number.

Comment: Yes there is, but his format does not allow is since it he has sometimes integers, sometimes strings. Or am I mistaken ? You seem to imply the contrary :)

Comment: I think the OP wants to be able able to ignore the `"`. I would use a method which returns a `double` and cast that. Possibly with some rounding.

Comment: I thought the parse would fail for `"5"` because it is not a numeric field. I'll try that